# doubt on test class implementation for a before trigger on Account

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have written one trigger for account where i am appending IND to the newly created account name.I have written a test class for the same.When i wrote test class i am creating a testAccount but after DML operation the account name of test account is not getting appended with IND.But it should append as i think.Let me know where i have gone wrong in implementing test class.Below are my code for the same.

Apex Trigger:

```
trigger AccountConcat on Account (before insert) {
    for(Account a :Trigger.new){
        a.name = 'IND' + a.name;
        System.debug('Value of acc name :::'+a.name);

    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class AccountConcat_Test {
    public static testmethod void concattest(){
        Account acc = new Account(name='testAccount');
        insert acc;
        System.debug('val of account name ::::'+acc);
        System.debug('val of account name ::::'+acc.name);
        String expected = 'INDtestAccount';
        System.assertEquals(expected, acc.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want to **append** 'IND' to the `account.name`, you need to change the following line in you trigger as follows:

```
    a.name = 'IND' + a.name;
```

becomes

```
    a.name = a.name + 'IND';
```

What you're currently doing is **pre-pending** 'IND' to the `account.name`.

As for your test class, it should look a bit more like the following:

```
@isTest
public class AccountConcat_Test {

    public static testmethod void concattest(){

        List<Profile>ps = [select id from Profile where name = 'Standard User' limit 1];

        // Create the user to be used in this test.&nbsp; 

        User U0 = new User(alias ='u0tst', 
        email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
        emailencodingkey='UTF-8', 
        lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US', 
        localesidkey='en_US', 
        profileid = ps[0].Id, 
        timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', 
        username='standarduser@testorg.com');

        insert U0;

        RunAs(U0){

           integer n=0;

           list<Account> acc = new list<Account>(name='testAccount' + n, OwnerId = U0.Id );
           // add for loop here to get debug when list size greater than 1 (n>0)
           for(integer i=0; i<n; i++){

               System.debug('val of account name ::::'+ acc[i] );

           }

           test.startTest();

           insert acc;

           test.stopTest();   

           for(integer i=0;i<n;;i++){

              System.debug('val of account name ::::'+acc.name);

           } 

           // String expected = 'INDtestAccount';

           for(integer i=0;i<n;;i++){

              System.assertEquals(acc.name, acc.name + 'IND'); 
              //written for appending instead of pre-pending
              //change to 'IND' + acc.name if you actually do want to pre-pend
           }
       }// end runAs
    }//end method
}//end class
```

Note: Your org may have validation rules that make other fields required, such as shipping address and/or billing address, type, etc. You'll need to check your org's validation rules to determine what fields are required to make certain your test class populates them.

I've added the integer `n` variable and created everything as lists so you can bulk test your trigger once you know it works for a single record. This is a good practice to get in the habit of.

Comment: its pre-appending only.IND+AccountName=INDAccountName

Answer (score 0):

The objects in memory are not automatically updated when triggers act so in tests you have to re-query to check what happened:

```
System.assertEquals(expected, [select Name from Account where Id = :acc.Id].Name);
```

Note that triggers can fire more than once so I suggest your trigger should check for the prefix and only add it if it is not already present.

(Your trigger will impact all users and all apps in the org: seems very intrusive.)

Comment: I am getting error saying "System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: INDtestAccount, Actual: testAccount".Trigger is not appending IND to account name on insertion of account.

Comment: You make a good point on the checking first. As for the test class, in his case, he's not using Test.StartTest or test.StopTest. Once he does, he may not need to query.

Comment: @crmprogdev Those calls impact governor limits and collecting async requests - no effect on the query semantics. Suggest you remove the Profile/User/RunAs from your answer: not a good thing to include code that has no purpose.

Comment: It would seem to me that he needs to assign an owner to the Account. Thus the use of a RunAs or he could have just created the user and assigned it as the owner. Either way a user was needed for the assignment.

Comment: @crmprogdev The focus of the test is on naming not on ownership logic so letting the Account be owned by the User running the test is fine and normal